# How to link against a shared library which linked with different version of boost in linux

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, linkage

I'm building a executable in a big project, one of its dependency, a .so file, is linked against boost 1.6.2, and the executable itself must be static linked to a different version of boost, I don't know the version of that, maybe 1.6.0, when I link to the .so directly, it's able to compile and link, but when I run that binary, the behaviour of that binary becomes strange when calling to the functions of classes of the external .so file, such as it can run into infinite lock, and core dump inside boost. But if I don't link a different version of boost, it works. I guess the version of boost caused this problem. Is that true? How can I fix this?

Comment: The .so external library is aliyun rocketmq c++ SDK, document at here (in Chinese):https://m.aliyun.com/doc/document_detail/29555.html

Comment: That library only provide a .a and .so, when trying to link the .a, linker complains about multiple definition of boost stuff.

Comment: I solved it in .a by sed replacing 5boost to 5bzzst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest thing to do is to rename the namespace of your statically linked version of boost to ensure there are no symbol clashes. Unfortunately I don't think boost has any macros for changing its namespace so you'll have to do a manual find and replace in the source code.

Comment: It's really big project and hundreds of people are working on it, I can't simply change that.

Comment: I'm thinking about making a namespace to wrap the .so(or .a), but I don't have source code of that. Is that possible?

Comment: the problem is that if your executable defines the boost symbols then when the shared library is loaded it will use the existing boost symbols rather than loading them itself from the boost shared library. If you are very careful to not export any boost symbols from your executable it may work but its quite fiddly. Wrapping the shared library in a new namespace wont achieve anything.

Comment: you might have some success with: `#define boost boost_static`

Comment: Then can I wrap the static library in a new namespace? Say, the boost symbols in it becomes foo:: boost and all references to boost in itself also becomes foo::boost. Is that possible? And if it's possible will it work?

Comment: you could rename the symbols in the static library but you'd also have to rename the symbols in your executable to link to the library

Comment: I assume that "#define boost boost_static" only works if I add that to all related headers. But I can't do that because it a big project.

Comment: you could add it to something like boost config which is included everywhere

Comment: Renaming the symbols of my source code that related to that library is OK. Because I want to import that external library to our project and now no code are actually using that external library.